# Error al recuperar registro con una propiedad null en Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

al intentar obtener un registro en ORACLE y el valor de la propiedad la cual utilizo luego para hacer una validación contiene un valor null da error de consulta

```
Informe de error -
ORA-01403: No se ha encontrado ningún dato
ORA-06512: en línea 38
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Comparto la consulta

```
Tabla :[r5addetails]
Propiedades de la tabla:

[add_code = '3340.00.114.10.3';
ADD_TEXT = null;
add_rentity = 'TASK';
add_type='*';
add_lang='ES';]

    DECLARE
        codigo VARCHAR2(2000) :='3340.00.114.10.3';
        long_var LONG;
        vv   VARCHAR2 (2000);
        nuevasReferencias VARCHAR2(2000); 
        add_refes_in VARCHAR2(2000) :='MCG.26.10.2017';
    BEGIN
        Select ADD_TEXT INTO long_var FROM r5addetails where add_code=(codigo||'#0') and add_rentity='TASK' and add_type='*' and add_lang='ES'; 
        nuevasReferencias:= REPLACE (add_refes_in,'####', CHR(10));
        vv:=long_var;
        dbms_output.put_line( vv );
        if instr( vv, 'REF:' ) != 0 then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('NUEVA REFERENCIA: ' || SUBSTR(vv,0,INSTR(vv,'REF:',1,1)-1)||' REF:'|| nuevasReferencias);
          else
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('AGREGAR NUEVA REFERENCIA: ' || vv ||' REF:'|| nuevasReferencias);
         end if;
    END;
```

Alguna idea, de como evitar ese error y tratar de devolver un valor en blanco o algo?. Gracias

NOTA: No por ganar puntos comente **como hacer la pregunta**, agradecería la solución antes que criticar la forma de escribir. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta:

Envuelvo la consulta con un Begin/Exception para detectar que la propiedad la cual utilizo (ADD_TEXT) de la tabla es null.

```
 DECLARE
        codigo VARCHAR2(2000) :='3340.00.114.10.3';
        long_var LONG;
        vv   VARCHAR2 (2000);
        nuevasReferencias VARCHAR2(2000); 
        add_refes_in VARCHAR2(2000) :='MCG.26.10.2017';

    BEGIN
        Select ADD_TEXT INTO long_var FROM r5addetails where add_code=(codigo||'#0') and add_rentity='TASK' and add_type='*' and add_lang='ES'; 
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            long_var:=NULL;
    END;

    nuevasReferencias:= REPLACE (add_refes_in,'####', CHR(10));
    vv:=long_var;
    dbms_output.put_line( vv );
    if instr( vv, 'REF:' ) != 0 then
        --UPDATE r5addetails SET ADD_TEXT = SUBSTR(vv,0,INSTR(vv,'REF:',1,1)-1)||' REF:'|| referencias where add_code=(codigo||'#0') and add_rentity='TASK' and add_type='*' and add_lang='ES';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('NUEVA REFERENCIA: ' || SUBSTR(vv,0,INSTR(vv,'REF:',1,1)-1)||' REF:'|| nuevasReferencias);
      else
        --UPDATE r5addetails SET ADD_TEXT = vv ||' REF:'|| referencias where add_code=(codigo||'#0') and add_rentity='TASK' and add_type='*' and add_lang='ES';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('AGREGAR NUEVA REFERENCIA: ' || vv ||' REF:'|| nuevasReferencias);
     end if;
END;
```

Saludos.